# VM and local network access with Port forwarding in UTM on M1

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, home-networking, sql-server

I'd like to connect a Win11 arm VM inside UTM on macOS M1 to a Win10 intel macbook pro in Bootcamp mode on my local network (wifi). I was advised to "use Emulated VLAN with port forwarding on and then forward the port to your host mac." I'm not sure how to accomplish  "port forwarding on and then forward the port to your host mac".

I'm confused about port forwarding in general. I understand that [Windows file sharing runs on UDP and CTP on port 445](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) inside my Win11 VM. Ok so I'm not really sure what I'm trying to accomplish with "port forwarding". Say I forward it to a different port, 40445, on the Win11 VM. Would that break Windows file sharing since it is no longer receiving the File sharing protocol on port 445? (Eventually I'll use SQL server on the network, but that's another port.)

I'm open to suggestions for other ways of connecting the VM to the local windows computer.